# Can EU citizens work in Iceland?

Tags: legal, europe

From Wikipedia:

> Iceland is heavily integrated into the European Union via the European
>   Economic Area and the Schengen Agreement, but it is not a member
>   state.

Because Iceland is not a member state I guess rules for moving and work in the country are different.

1. Can europeans work in Iceland? How long can we stay there?

Comment: @phoog can be moved to exp?

Comment: People in Iceland may object to the use of "on Iceland" ([except perhaps on Fridays](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/21413#21413)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While Iceland is not a member of EU, it participates in the EU Single Market through its membership of the [European Economic Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Economic_Area). One consequence of that is that [freedom of movement for workers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_movement_for_workers_in_the_European_Union) applies to Iceland and Icelanders *in the same way as to the EU proper*.

An EU citizen has the right to live and work in Iceland indefinitely without prior permission (but must register with civil authorities within 6 months, like native Icelanders have to). The rules also give quite liberal rights to move to Iceland to *seek work* on your own expense for up to six months.

The Icelandic government informs about the procedure at https://www.skra.is/english/individuals/moving-to-iceland/